# Any good opensource SharePoint components that can abstract you from the inner SharePoint plumbings?

Tags: .net, sharepoint, components

I am looking for a good reusable set of components that can be used to communicate with SharePoint via web services, preferably open source.

I want some abstraction from CAML and WebDav and SharePoint Web Services that could help me speed up my development time.

Ideally I want to select, insert, update and delete from lists, manage attachments in list items, download items from sharepoint, retrieve user meta data from owner info. This sort of thing.

Does any such abstraction exist for Sharepoint that use SharePoints web service model, obviously the use of the MOSS Component API is out of the question because it will only run on the hosted MOSS server, and I am writing an SOA app.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Why it's not opensource and it's available only for SharePoint 2010, Microsoft has done a good job of making the SharePoint API accessible on client platforms with their Client Object Model. Versions exist for Websites based on JavaScript, a managed .NET dll for Winforms/WPF and  Silverlight client. More information at

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee537013(v=office.14).aspx

Not sure of anything for SP 2007 other than the OTB Web Services.

Comment: Hi John, are you saying these client Context objects can be called remotely, unlike in SharePoint 2007, where you had to call object model from local moss server?

Comment: I think so... :) For example, the Silverlight version has a managed DLL that gets deployed with your XAP file. Your silverlight app calls the Client Object Model (managed DLL) which then calls the remote MOSS Server. It's essentially a (very NICE) wrapper around the calls to the MOSS server, but you are not calling the Web Servcies directly